# How to connect to SignalR server, from Xamarin client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.android, signalr

(**) I created an ASP.NET web server, hosting SignalR hub. I followed [this](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)
tutorial. It works. Then I created a Xamarin.Android client(*). The problem is I can't connected to the server. I think, I can't connected because of "localhost" in my host address. The exception is pretty big.

If my suspicions are correct, how can I work around? How can I make localhost looks like normal server?

(*) - I also tried with Xamarin.Forms in general.

(**) - Please, look at the "EDIT" at the bottom of the question.

This is my method:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        button.Click += async delegate 
        {
            button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++);
            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:64642");
            var chatHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
            try
            {
                // Start the connection
                await hubConnection.Start();

                // Invoke the 'UpdateNick' method on the server
                await chatHubProxy.Invoke("Send", new object[] { "TheMessage", "JohnDoe" });
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        };
    }
```

> {System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)
>   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP)
>   [0x000cb] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:1313
>   at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest
>   request) [0x0019b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:195
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) [0x0005e] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1023
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic
>   (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction,
>   System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult]
>   promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00014] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:550
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult
>   () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+c__async0.MoveNext ()
>   [0x003ce] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:379
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult
>   () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+c__async0.MoveNext ()
>   [0x000a9] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:276
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113
>   at
>   AndroidApp.MainActivity+<>c__DisplayClass1_0+<b__0>d.MoveNext
>   () [0x000a5] in
>   C:\Data\Projects\SinglaRSamples\AndroidApp\AndroidApp\MainActivity.cs:36
>   }

EDIT:

as **mason** and **Jason** suggested, I probably have to use the proper IP instead of "localhost". The IP that Android Emulator see the actual localhost. I'm struggling to find that IP, it's somewhere in Android Settings. Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you actually running SignalR server on your Android device?

Comment: use the IP or FQDN of your server.  "localhost" refers back to the Android device itself.

Comment: @mason what do you mean? I'm not running the server on Android device. I'm running it in ASPNET website, on localhost. Android device is a client.

Comment: Well if you're running an ASP.NET website on a server, and your Xamarin app is running on an Android device, then they're not running on the same machine. Localhost means "same machine". Instead of using localhost in the URL, you'd include the IP address or DNS name of your server. As far as your app is concerned, the server is remote, not local.

Comment: @mason You didn't understand me. I have one computer. On this computer I'm running ASP.NET Web project, where I host signalR hub and I'm running an emulator with Xamarin.Android. The same computer.

Comment: It might be the same physical computer, but the app is running on Android emulator inside a Virtual machine, right? So again, you need to provide the correct address to get to the host machine where the sever is actually running. Check the network settings for your VM.

Comment: @Jason I'm on VMWare vm (the computer is Macbook), I'm running a vm with windows. On this VM I'm running everything. Are you suggestion to replace "localhost" with my IP address, like `192.168.123.123:64642/` ? If so, it doesn't work.. I have an error in the browser: `HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.` (when I go to localhost:64642 - I have a sample chat app, from the tutorial)

Comment: The principle is still the exact same. If your ASP.NET server is running on a Windows VM, and you are running the Android emulator VM within that VM, then you need to go into the Android emulator VM's network settings and determine what the correct address is that should be used to refer to the host (Windows VM). This [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779282/how-to-connect-to-localhost-from-vs-android-emulator) is similar. You should take a few minutes to learn about virtualization and how virtual networks are set up - it seems like you're confused on the basics.

Comment: ohh, that would make sense. Although, can't find those settings. I'm using the new emulator (HAXM). I probably need to disable LTE, correct?

Comment: I doubt LTE has much to do with it. I suggest checking documentation or asking Intel how to check that setting. Or using a different emulator with better documentation.

Comment: @Jason Do you know how to get this IP from Android Emulator settings? I'm struggling to find it :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing localhost(Xamarin)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240185/accessing-localhostxamarin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the ASP.NET site running on your PC host using http://10.0.2.2:64642 from the Google SDK emulator. If it fails to reach the server then you probably need to configure the Windows Firewall to allow incoming HTTP/HTTPS connections.

Comment: can I use SignalR in my webservice? as I have a Xamarin android app that is connected to the web service and I want the webservice to notify the client about the data change.?

Comment: what is the IP for ios windows remote simulator