# SignalR Client in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to add the SignalR client to a Xamarin.Forms project.

I see that there are 2 packages, one for .Net and the other for .NetCore

> Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client

and

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client

The project that I am adding it to is a `.Net Standard 2` project

But whenever I run the app, I get the following exception

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client, Version=2.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. assembly:Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client, Version=2.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 type: member:(null) signature:

and

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. assembly:Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 type: member:(null) signature:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42047657/singalr-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: @Jason I have tried that. That is when it is claiming that it cannot load a dependancy. This is failing to load the main assembly.

Comment: @Jason I have also gone through each package and installed each dependency individually.  Still get the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aspnet core version of signalr is not ready for Xamarin yet. See [this](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1886#issuecomment-394807590).

Comment: It is _supposedly_ ready now with Visual Studio 2017 15.8 Preview 3, although it has not fixed the issue for me, even on a fresh project. Some additional dependencies are required. See https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/305